# Sum from element 1 to current element in R

Tags: r

I've come across the `aggregate()` function and things like `seq_along()`, but I'm not sure how to solve this yet:

For the following:

```
x
1
5
10
20
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```
y
1
6
16
36
```

It seemed to me that doing something like `x[1:seq_along(x)]` would do the trick but it seems not because `seq_along(x)` is a sequence rather than a number.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @DavidArenburg, you can use the `cumsum` function:

```
x <- c(1, 5, 10, 20)

cumsum(x)

[1]  1  6 16 36
```